# DrawRect overriding properties of view

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, xcode6

I'm creating a custom view which will basically just be a checkmark inside a cirlce. I've created a circle using `layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * frame.width` but when I override drawRect, it causes that line to be ignored and my view becomes a square.

Why is this? And how can I fix this so I can create the circle with a checkmark inside it?

Here is my current code:

```
class CheckMarkView: UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * frame.width
        backgroundColor = .whiteColor()
        hidden = true
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add clipsToBounds to true, and takes all the frame that is available to it.

```
      class CheckMarkView: UIView {

        override init(frame: CGRect) {
            super.init(frame: frame)

            layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * frame.width
            backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            clipsToBounds = true
        }

        required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        }

        override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
            super.drawRect(rect)
        }
      }
```